# Why broadcast receiver is called even no intent filter specified?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, broadcast

As in title, broadcast receiver get called even no intent filter is specified in android manifest or in code. Even I specify concrete intent action in manifest like:

```
  <receiver
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_network_wifi_on"
            android:name=".receivers.WifiReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

The receiver get called when no airplane mode change.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Presumably, you are either calling `sendBroadcast()` yourself, or you are using a broadcast `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Ive just created new clean launcher activity and this receiver still get called. Does the receiver xml look good?

Comment: It looks fine. `AIRPLANE_MODE` *might* be a sticky broadcast, which might explain why you would get a broadcast for it with no change in the airplane mode status.

Comment: I think there were issue with existing service running in bg but not visible as a process so that it were detected.